The solutions of $(2p^x)^{\varphi(2p^x)}+z^{\varphi(z)}=(2q^y)^{\varphi(2q^y)}$, being $\varphi(n)$ the Euler's totient.
The solutions of $(2p^x)^{\varphi(2p^x)}+z^{\varphi(z)}=(2q^y)^{\varphi(2q^y)}$, being $\varphi(n)$ the Euler's totient such that $p \neq q$ are primes, $v_2(z)=1$ and $\exists \ r_1,r_2 : r_1 \mid z \ \land \ r_2 \mid z$ where $r_1,r_2$ are odd primes, we also must have $\varphi(2q^y)=\varphi(z)$ along with $x,y \geq 2$.
The source of this is a modified form of unknown original source. The reasons for the conditions are that it is a subcase of the original question however I would like to try and see where this goes. A few things I tried doing is considering $$z=2\prod_{i=1}^n r_i^{k_i} \implies \varphi(z)=\prod_{i=1}^n r_i^{k_i-1}(r_i-1) \implies \prod_{i=1}^n r_i^{k_i-1}(r_i-1)=q^{y-1}(q-1)$$ and then trying to do some divisibility arguments with regard to $q \mid \prod_{i=1}^n r_i^{k_i-1}(r_i-1)$ however since $p \neq q$ we have that $q \nmid z$ as otherwise it'd contradict our condition. Thus we have $1=gcd(z,q)=gcd(r_i,q)=gcd(r_i^{k_i-1},q)$ using some divisibility propeties and the fact that $r_i,q$ are primes. Thus we have $q \mid \prod_{i=1}^n (r_i-1)$ and perhaps some argument with regard to Euclid's Lemma however I couldn't proceed much. The other idea I have tried was considering $z=2u$ where $u \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 2)$ since $v_2(z)=1$ and then we have $\varphi(2q^y)=\varphi(z)=\varphi(2u)=\varphi(u)$ so, $$v_2((2p^x)^{\varphi(2p^x)}+z^{\varphi(z)})=v_2((2q^y)^{\varphi(2q^y)}) \implies v_2((2p^x)^{p^{x-1}(p-1)}+(2u)^{\varphi(u)})=q^{y-1}(q-1) \implies v_2((2p^x)^{p^{x-1}(p-1)}+(2u)^{q^{y-1}(q-1)})=q^{y-1}(q-1)$$ Now we introduce a lemma $q^{y-1}(q-1) \neq p^{x-1}(p-1)$ which is as follows :
Proof : F.T.S.O.C assume that $q^{y-1}(q-1) = p^{x-1}(p-1)$. We notice that $p \mid q^{y-1}(q-1) \implies p \mid q-1$ due to $p \neq q$ and $x-1 \geq 1$. Similarly we get $q \mid p^{x-1}(p-1) \implies q \mid p-1$ due to $p \neq q$ and $y-1 \geq 1$. But this leads to $q \leq p-1 \leq q-2$ which is a strict contradiction! Thus we are done.
Now using the above lemma, assume that $p^{x-1}(p-1)<q^{y-1}(q-1)$ then we have, $$v_2(2^{p^{x-1}(p-1)}(p^{xp^{x-1}(p-1)}+2^{q^{y-1}(q-1)-p^{x-1}(p-1)}u^{q^{y-1}(q-1)}))=q^{y-1}(q-1)$$ $$(p^{xp^{x-1}(p-1)}+2^{q^{y-1}(q-1)-p^{x-1}(p-1)}u^{q^{y-1}(q-1)}) \equiv 1 \ (mod \ 2)$$ these statements imply that the first equation reduces to, $$v_2(2^{p^{x-1}(p-1)})=q^{y-1}(q-1) \implies p^{x-1}(p-1)=q^{y-1}(q-1)$$ this is a strict contradiction! Thus we have some inequality that $p^{x-1}(p-1)>q^{y-1}(q-1) \implies \varphi(2p^x)>\varphi(2p^y)$.
At this point, after trying this for an hour I was quite tired so I just let my brain reset. In the meantime however, I would surely like to see someone answer the following:

Am I going on the wrong path?
Is there any general method for these kinds of questions specifically regarding analysis or perhaps some growth arguments ?
Are there any errors in my arguments till now ?
Some book recommendations for theory pertaining to this specifically (related topic).

I am also citing the original question here which is $$a^{\varphi(a)}+b^{\varphi(b)}=c^{\varphi(c)} \ \text{where} \ a,b,c \geq 2$$
Some insight on the original question : Basically I am considering the fact that there are no solutions to $x^4+y^2=z^4$ and $x^4+y^4=z^2$ and simplifying to cases wherein $4 \mid \varphi$. For that I'm consider number of odd prime divisors which obviously plays a role, then the $v_2(x)$ as this with the lemma that $v_2(\varphi(x)) \geq v_2(x)-1$ is strong. I'm also considering $p \equiv 3 (mod \ 4)$ condition. One can perhaps rebuild the map I followed to reach the case where I am now. However talking about this would be a very long post. So I just posted the subcase, also I feel better not looking at the solution of the whole thing so as to strengthen my NT. (Kindly do not post the solution to the original problem). However a question about this part is that : Am I on the right path or is my solution style non conclusive or too bashy? (If yes, I would like some subtle hints).
Thanks a lot!
